# Performance difference in c# linq query

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Assuming I have list of files:

```
List<string> files = GetFiles();
```

By performance aspect, Is the code:

```
var orderedFiles = files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).OrderBy(f.LastWriteTime);
```

equals to:

```
var orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(new FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime);
```

and if not so which one is better ? (assuming I don't really need the ordered list to be 'FileInfo' type)

Comment: Just try it out. *Measure*

Comment: Define "performance". Speed, memory, ease of readability and maintenance?

Comment: Measure you mean by Stopwatch before and after ?

Comment: By performance I mean 2 aspects - memory allocation and also speed to execute

Comment: Does your second one even compile?

Comment: By memory allocation the second should be better - anything that calculates with the first `orderedFiles` will require the entire list of `FileInfo` objects to be instantiated and hang around for the `OrderBy` to process and the answer to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into the [Benchmark.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for the performance like speed and memory allocation.